# I can reach OpenVPN server from inside LAN but not from outside anymore

Tags: ubuntu, openvpn

I configured openvpn server and everything work well, but now i cant connect to openvpn server from outside network with same conf.ovpn

Port forwarding and firewall is checked

I got this error in syslog when trying to connect from outside network

```
Oct 29 14:57:54 server openvpn[9297]: 89.47.69.149:27213 tls-crypt unwrap error: packet replay
Oct 29 14:57:54 server openvpn[9297]: 89.47.69.149:27213 TLS Error: tls-crypt unwrapping failed from [AF_INET]89.47.69.149:27213
Oct 29 14:57:59 server systemd-timesyncd[764]: Timed out waiting for reply from 91.189.91.157:123 (ntp.ubuntu.com).
Oct 29 14:58:00 server openvpn[9297]: 89.47.69.149:27213 UDPv4 WRITE [54] to [AF_INET]89.47.69.149:27213: P_CONTROL_HARD_RESET_SERVER_V2 kid=0 [ ] pid=1125 DATA len=40
Oct 29 14:58:09 server systemd-timesyncd[764]: Timed out waiting for reply from 185.125.190.57:123 (ntp.ubuntu.com).
Oct 29 14:58:17 server openvpn[9297]: 89.47.69.149:27213 UDPv4 WRITE [54] to [AF_INET]89.47.69.149:27213: P_CONTROL_HARD_RESET_SERVER_V2 kid=0 [ ] pid=1381 DATA len=40
Oct 29 14:58:19 server systemd-timesyncd[764]: Timed out waiting for reply from 185.125.190.58:123 (ntp.ubuntu.com).
Oct 29 14:58:30 server systemd-timesyncd[764]: Timed out waiting for reply from 185.125.190.56:123 (ntp.ubuntu.com).
Oct 29 14:58:46 server openvpn[9297]: 89.47.69.149:27213 TLS Error: TLS key negotiation failed to occur within 60 seconds (check your network connectivity)
Oct 29 14:58:46 server openvpn[9297]: 89.47.69.149:27213 TLS Error: TLS handshake failed
```

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.